# Regularity of functions approximated with neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

Are there any papers pertaining to smoothness / regularity of functions that are approximated with artificial neural network?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, there are many. The one that gets cited the most is Hornik's paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089360809190009T

You can easily find it with a Google search if you hit a paywall.

Comment: Didn't get the -1. The OP wanted some references and I provided him with the main reference in which the author discusses his assumptions wrt smoothness and regularity of functions that can be approximated with a very simple ANN. Seemed to me to be a really good starting point as he didn't ask for any explanation, just references...

Comment: Did an upvote. I agree didn't deserve a downvote.